# How does the persistence work in XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, amqp

I'm trying to understand the differences between AMQP and XMPP and among other things I don't really understand if XMPP works like it had Queues. 
When you send a message to various clients what happen if one of them is down? The server enqueues the message up to the client is up again or how does it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the XMPP server implementation how messages and iq's are handeld when the JID is offline. [Section 11.1 of RFC 3921](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#rules):

> Else if the JID is of the form  and there are no
>   available resources associated with the user, how the stanza is
>   handled depends on the stanza type:
>
> ...
>
> For message stanzas, the server MAY choose to store the stanza on
>   behalf of the user and deliver it when the user next becomes
>   available, or forward the message to the user via some other means
>   (e.g., to the user's email account). However, if offline message
>   storage or message forwarding is not enabled, the server MUST return
>   to the sender a  stanza error. (Note: Offline
>   message storage and message forwarding are not defined in XMPP, since
>   they are strictly a matter of implementation and service
>   provisioning.)
>
> For IQ stanzas, the server itself MUST reply on behalf of the user
>   with either an IQ result or an IQ error. Specifically, if the
>   semantics of the qualifying namespace define a reply that the server
>   can provide, the server MUST reply to the stanza on behalf of the
>   user; if not, the server MUST reply with a 
>   stanza error.

Comment: Thanks!. so it can be very similar to QUEUE system. It's difficult to see the difference

Comment: Keep in mind that there is no end-to-end delivery guarantee in XMPP.  It intends short latency at the expense of careful safe-storing at each hop with 2-phase commit acks.